# How do I change the output values to 2 decimal places?

Tags: jquery, decimal, calculator

I would like the Total and No. of Cans to display in 2 decimal places:

```
$('input').keyup(function () { // run anytime the value changes


var firstValue = parseFloat($('#width').val()); // get value of field
var secondValue = parseFloat($('#height').val());
var thirdValue = parseFloat($('#per-can').val()); // convert it to a float
var forthValue = parseFloat($('#cost').val());
var fithValue = parseFloat($('#size').val());

$('#added').html(firstValue * secondValue / thirdValue * forthValue);
$('#cans').html(firstValue * secondValue / thirdValue);

});
```

Also, as an added challenge, could I have an extra output, say named 'minimum cans needed' and it displays the amount based on a round up - for eg. if No. of cans = >1 but <2 then min cans needed = 2?

here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5xzSy/485/ can anyone help me based on that example?

Comment: Have a look at [`.toFixed`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp). You might also need [`parseFloat`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) in conjunction with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
var canCount = firstValue * secondValue / thirdValue;

$('#added').html((canCount * forthValue).toFixed(2));
$('#cans').html(canCount.toFixed(2));

if (Math.ceil(canCount) < 2) {
    // show error that at least two are needed
}
```

- [**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5xzSy/487/)

As an additional suggestion, you should name your variables something meaningful, as I have with `canCount`.

Comment: thank you - could i ask for a few more additions please? 1. is there an efficient way to create more number of cans needed exceptions, say <1 to <20? and 2. what ever the minimum required cans are, can the cost reflect that by multiplying by 18.23 and giving the real amount?

Comment: I'm going to answer frankly that (1) yes, there is; and (2) yes, it can. These are good questions but it would more appropriate to post a new question with your new code and the questions you've asked in the comment.

Comment: Hi cory, I did just that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803495/roundup-total-and-multiply-again-jquery-calculator

Comment: Please help, I have a 5pm BST deadline

Comment: @James: Please remember this isn't a "gimme teh codez" kind of site. You have to show effort for effort to be given. I've already given enough code where you should be able to apply the concepts to your new questions.

Comment: please believe me when i say i tried to work these things out myself using only educated guesses as i am more of a designer than a programmer: I'm doing a brief for a job interview with a 5pm bst deadline and this calculator is just 1 small part of the brief...